# Is it possible to track form submissions as clicks?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

I've been building an email in SFMC that contains a form for submitting a review.

The code looks something like this:

```
%%[
    var @sku1ReviewURL
    set @sku1ReviewURL = "http://somereviewURL.com"
]%%
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="POST" action="%%=v(@sku1ReviewURL)=%%" target="_blank" style="font-size:0;">
<!-- other form fields-->
<input name="submitButton" type="submit" value="submit review &raquo;" style="background: #84bd00; 
color: #fff; padding: 10px; border: 0; cursor: pointer; display: block; font-size: 16px; 
font-weight: bold; width: 324px; -webkit-appearance: none; border-radius: 0;" 
alias="rate_product1_button">
</form>
```

Is there a go-to method for tracking these form submissions as a click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for this but it is a little hacky. Basically you want to take the URL you're POSTing to and wrap that in ET's link tracking before adding it to your action attribute. There doesn't seem to be an AMPscript function for this so I hacked together a solution that uses HTTPGETWRAP to trick ET into thinking you have some external content you want to use. ET will track the URL in the content and then you extract it. Here is the code sample and test I put together:

```
    %%[
        /* create your fake content */
        set @fakedContent = "<a href='httpgetwrap|http://somereviewURL.com' alias='form submission'>"

        /* use TreatAsContent() so ET will wrap the URL */
        set @trackedContent = TreatAsContent(@fakedContent)

        /* use replace to remove the unwanted HTML so you are left with just the URL */
        set @trackedURL = Replace(Replace(@trackedContent,"<a href='",""),"' ></a>","") 
    ]%%

    <h1>TRACKED URL</h1>
    %%=v(@trackedURL)=%%

    <h1>TEST FORM</h1>
    <form action="%%=v(@trackedURL)=%%" method="POST">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Also make sure that you have the **WRAP HTTPGET URLS** business rule enabled for your account. You have to call SFMC support for this.

Comment: Does the alias get replaced with blank?

Comment: Yeah, the alias attribute is stripped from the tag and it leaves a space between the closing single quote and greater than symbol, which looks like this: `' >`.  I've verified in my account that the link is tracked under the alias name as well. A safer solution might be to run a replace for each of the 3 characters just to be sure: `'`,`  ` and `>` - that way if ET decides to add or remove any more spaces you're covered.

Comment: Very nice, Jon.  Got it to work.  Looks all jacked up in Send Preview (since the `treatascontent()` function hasn't fired), but once the send happens, it's fine.